# A generic way to curry functions in Julia

Tags: functional-programming, julia, currying

What are some idiomatic ways to achieve function currying?

Eg. in Haskell:

```hs
times a b = a * b
-- This can then be used uncurried:
times 2 3     -- Result is 6
-- But there is also auto-currying:
(times 2) 3   -- This works too
```

In Julia, some built-ins support this:

```
<(8, 7)    # Result is false
<(7)(8)    # Same
7 |> <(8)  # Same
```

However, user-defined functions don't automatically have this functionality:

```
times(a, b) = a * b
times(2, 3)    # Result is 6
3 |> times(2)  # MethodError: no method matching times(::Int64)
```

I can manually define a one-argument version like this:

```
times(a) = b -> a * b
```

But my question is, is there a *generic* operator or function that achieves this and works for both user-defined and built-in functions?

Comment: It looks like the Julia devs did [exactly what you did](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/36034abf26062acad4af9dcec7c4fc53b260dbb4/base/operators.jl#L1189-L1199) for `<` (only difference is they defined a helper struct called `Fix2` to make it a bit more consistent). That's not to say there *isn't* a better way, just saying that Julia's standard lib isn't doing some insane metaprogramming to get that behavior.

Comment: Using packages like `Pipe` and `Underscores` you can write `@pipe 3 |> times(2,_)` and `@_ 3 |> times(2,_)` respectively, and get the expected result. It looks quite close to currying, and might be enough.

Comment: Notice that `<(8)(7)` returns the _opposite_ result of `<(8, 7)`, so it isn't consistent with currying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why not use [curry.jl](https://github.com/Orbots/Curry.jl)

```
times(a, b) = a * b
times_curry = curry(times)
times_curry(5)(2) ---> gives 10
```

Comment: Warning, as far as the source code shows, it's limited to 4 calls deep currying only. Works for `times` in this case, but not for every purpose.

Answer (score -1):

This would be pretty tricky (impossible?) to solve in Julia without a macro, as multiple dispatch means you won't know which function you'll ultimately end up dispatching to until you see all of the arguments. I think the simplest way to implement currying is just with a struct like this:

```
julia> struct Curry
       func::Function
       args::Tuple
       Curry(func, args...) = new(func, args)
       end

julia> (curry::Curry)(x, args...) = Curry(curry.func, curry.args..., x, args...)

julia> (curry::Curry)() = curry.func(curry.args...)

julia> Curry(<)
Curry(<, ())

julia> Curry(<)(2)()
(::Base.Fix2{typeof(<), Int64}) (generic function with 1 method)

julia> Curry(<)(2)(3)()
true

julia> Curry(<, 2)
Curry(<, (2,))

julia> Curry(<, 2, 3)()
true
```

Basically, calling the `Curry` with at least one argument creates a new `Curry` with the new arguments, and calling it with 0 arguments “executes” the whole thing.